# Karate - How to pass a variable to another feature file using table

Tags: api, testing, karate

After doing some reading, I have figured out how to send variables to another feature file. However, how do I pass a variable when I am using a table?

The setup is:

```
        * table valueTable
            | number | mode         | time   | status |
            | 12345  | mobile       | 100    | 200    |
        * call read('feature1.feature@scenario1') valueTable
```

So if I use the following line to pass variable through, I get failures:

```
        * call read('feature1.feature@scenario1') {table1: '#(valueTable)', payload1: '#(payload)'}
```

Of course in above, 'payload' is the variable I want to pass to the second feature file. I don't have any issues passing variables if there is no table involved.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Put this in a new feature:

```
* table valueTable
    | number | mode         | time   | status |
    | 12345  | 'mobile'     | 100    | 200    |
* call read('called.feature') { table1: '#(valueTable)' }
```

And in `called.feature` have this:

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
* print __arg
```

And it works fine. So if you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I am also passing a variable along with the table variable in my call read. My variable and call read line looks like this:
abc = "string"
* call read('feature1.feature@scenario1') {table1: '#(valueTable)', payload1: '#(abc)'}

On feature1.feature file, I have a JS function where I am setting a new variable to "abc" variable. Out of that, I get an error: Cannot read property "length" from undefined

It doesn't seem to recognize my variable that I am sending across.

Comment: @hungryhippos I can help only if you follow the process. hopefully someone else adds an answer

Comment: Sorry about that @Peter Thomas, I just filed a ticket in Github.

Comment: @hungryhippos I'm sorry take 10 minutes and read this all the way to the end please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue